# Aggregations On HotChocolate Graphql

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am new to [HotChocolate](https://chillicream.com/) and I am seriously try to add aggregates like sum, average, count and etc. to my graphql backend. So, the frontend could query the aggregations without doing additional efforts on backend. something like [hasura](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/queries/aggregation-queries.html) queries:

```
query {
  article_aggregate {
    aggregate {
      count
      sum {
        rating
      }
      avg {
        rating
      }
      max {
        rating
      }
    }
    nodes {
      id
      title
      rating
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: At the moment you can extend the connection type and add aggregations. But this is something manual. Aggregations like in hasura are on our list for version 12.

Comment: @MichaelIngmarStaib Do you have an example on how we could do this with extending connection type? We are looking to do sum aggregates on the total data set prior to paging being applied.

Comment: Found this github page..
https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/discussions/2963

Comment: Essentially you can do ...


```
[ExtendObejctType("ArticleConnection")]
public class ConnectionExtension 
{
    public SumAggregate GetSum() => ....
}
```